# Bash - readarray contains only one element

Tags: bash, scripting, scripting-language

I'm writing this script to count some variables from an input file. I can't figure out why it is not counting the elements in the array (should be 500) but only counts 1.

```
#initializing variables 
timeout=5
headerFile="lab06.output"
dataFile="fortune500.tsv"
dataURL="http://www.tech.mtu.edu/~toarney/sat3310/lab09/"
dataPath="/home/pjvaglic/Documents/labs/lab06/data/"
curlOptions="--silent --fail --connect-timeout $timeout"

#creating the array
declare -a myWebsitearray #=('cut -d '\t' -f3 "dataPath$dataFile"')

#obtaining the data file
wget $dataURL$dataFile -O $dataPath$dataFile

#getting rid of the crap from dos
sed -e "s/^m//" $dataPath$dataFile | readarray -t $myWebsitesarray

readarray -t myWebsitesarray < <(cut -d, -f3 $dataPath$dataFile)

myWebsitesarray=("${#myWebsitesarray[@]:1}")

#printf '%s\n' "${myWebsitesarray2[@]}"

websitesCount=${#myWebsitesarray[*]}

echo $websitesCount
```

Comment: Start with shellcheck.net. You've also got a problem with using `readarray` in a pipe, although that line is somewhat irrelevant since you would be overriding whatever is in the array in the very next line that correctly uses process substitution to populate the array.

Comment: (And what's with the unused `curlOptions` when you are using `wget` anyway?)

Comment: It comes up later in the script, this is only half of it. I just can't even get it to count.

Comment: You've got a few issues here, note @chepner's point about the first time you do `readarray`.  But, take this one step at a time.  After each operation you do on `myWebsitesarray`, take a look at its contents and make sure they match what you expect.  For instance, try `echo "${#myWebsitesarray[@]:1}"` after your second `readarray`.

Comment: I cleaned it up, it's working correctly. I appreciate the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your array with the count of elements in this line

`myWebsitesarray=("${#myWebsitesarray[@]:1}")`

Remove the hash sign

`myWebsitesarray=("${myWebsitesarray[@]:1}")`

Also, @chepner suggestions are good to follow.